# Object passed into Redux store is not reflecting all key/values after mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component where toggle buttons are dynamically generated. Right now, I am just trying to get it working at a basic level so you click on a button and it adds a key/value pair to the `cuts = {}`.

After clicking on multiple buttons the `cuts` should have several key/value pairs: it does in the component where `cuts` resides, it does in the action, and it does in the Redux store via `console.log(state.cuts)`.

However, after `mapStateToProps` it is only showing the first value and I am not sure why.

Anyway, here is my code and the flow as it is initiated by the user:

```
// bq_cuts.js component
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cuts: {}
    }
}

onCutSelect(cut) {
    const { bqResults } = this.props;
    const { cuts } = this.state;

    let key = cut.name;
    let value = cut.value;

    cuts[key] = value;
    this.setState({
        cuts
    })
    console.log(cuts); // shows all of the selected cuts here
    bqResults(cuts);
}
```

---

```
// results.js actions
export function bqResults(results) {
    console.log(results); // shows all of the selected cuts here
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: FILTER_RESULTS,
            payload: results
        })
    }
}
```

---

```
// results.js reducer
import {
    FILTER_RESULTS
} from '../actions/results';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FILTER_RESULTS:
            console.log(action.payload); //prints out all the cuts
            return {
                ...state,
                filter_results: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

    return state;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    results: resultsReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

---

```
// bq_results.js component where the FILTER_RESULTS is accessed
render() {
    console.log(this.props.filter_results); // only shows the first result
    return (<div>...</div>)
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state.results.filter_results); // shows all selected cuts here
    return {
        filter_results: state.results.filter_results,
    }
}
```

Maybe a better way of putting it is it seems like after the initial state is mapped to props, it is no longer receiving changes to state and mapping it to props.

Comment: Can you please put your  ```reducer``` here.

Comment: Avoid reuse of the same state object. Create a new reference and try again.

Comment: @salman.zare Ok, posted the reducer.

Comment: @PRAISER is right your payload still points to the same  cuts reference, you must create a new one (clone the cuts object to a new one) in order for mapStateToProps to detect the change.

Comment: Would either of you mind explaining more? I thought I was following, but apparently I am not as I am getting the same result. For instance, I thought maybe you both were referring to the `cuts[key] = value; this.setState({cuts}); bqResults(cuts);` portion but I did assign the `state` `cuts` to a different variable after `this.setState` to pass into the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this article and used Approach #2:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5

Ended up with:

```
onCutSelect(cut) {
    let cuts = {...this.state.cuts, [cut]: cut}
    this.setState({
        cuts
    }, () => this.props.bqResults(this.state.cuts));

}
```