# delete not working in ternary in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I have been struggling with getting this section of the application working 100% as can be seen with these related questions:

[Method renders correctly when triggered one at a time, but not using _.map in React-Redux container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701956/method-renders-correctly-when-triggered-one-at-a-time-but-not-using-map-in-re)

[Object passed into Redux store is not reflecting all key/values after mapStateToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640777/object-passed-into-redux-store-is-not-reflecting-all-key-values-after-mapstateto)

So the setup is this... a bunch of buttons are dynamically generated based on the number of data "cuts" for a specific item (basically different ways of looking at the data like geography, business segment, etc.). The user can select one button at a time, click a Select All. This will retrieve the data related to the cut from the server and generate a table below the buttons.

One-at-a-time selections is working, select all is working, clear all is working. However, what I am trying to setup now is if the person clicks the same button again, it toggles that data point off.

This is where I was left after one of my previous questions:

```
onCutSelect(cut) {
    this.setState(
        ({cuts: prevCuts}) => ({cuts: {...prevCuts, [cut]: cut}}),
        () => this.props.bqResults(this.state.cuts)
    );
}
```

Works fine for one at a time selections and the Select All (this function is called via a `map` from a different function).

Modified to this, which I was hoping would toggle the data point off:

```
onCutSelect(cut) {
    this.setState(
        ({cuts: prevCuts}) => (
            this.state.cuts.hasOwnProperty(cut) 
            ? 
                delete this.state.cuts[cut] 
            : 
                {cuts: {...prevCuts, [cut]: cut}}),
        () => this.props.bqResults(this.state.cuts)
    );
```

What I would think should be happening, is checks if the `key` is there and if it is to delete it which will toggle the button off. And it does, it changes the button status to unselected.

However, what I would think should also happen, is since `this.state.cuts` is being modified, it will send the new `this.state` to the `this.props.bqResults` action. While the button is toggling off, it still shows the data related to the cut, so that store is not being updated for whatever reason. How should I be handling this?

Here is the remainder of the related code:

---

```
// results.js actions
export function bqResults(results) {
    console.log(results); // shows all of the selected cuts here
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: FILTER_RESULTS,
            payload: results
        })
    }
}
```

---

```
// results.js reducer
import {
    FILTER_RESULTS
} from '../actions/results';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FILTER_RESULTS:
            console.log(action.payload); //prints out all the cuts
            return {
                ...state,
                filter_results: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

    return state;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    results: resultsReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onCutSelect(cut) {
  this.setState(
      ({cuts: prevCuts}) => {
        if (cuts.hasOwnProperty(cut)) {
          const newCut = {...this.state.cuts}
          delete newCut[cut]
          return newCut
        } else {
          return {cuts: {...prevCuts, [cut]: cut}}
        }
      },
    () => this.props.bqResults(this.state.cuts)
  );
}
```

A few things. First, don't mutate state directly like that. Using `delete` removes the index number of the existing `this.state.cuts`. Perform this operation in a way that creates a completely new array when assigning your new value. I use the spread operator for this.

Also, when you return a delete operation, it's not returning what the array is after using `delete`. It returns `delete`'s return value, which in this case is a boolean.

```js
function delIdx(arr, idx) {
  return delete arr[idx]
 }
 
 console.log(delIdx([1,3,4], 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and explaining that. However, still running into the issue. The `delete` section isn't working and state remains the same. Taking a look at the issue more.

Comment: @sockpuppet Can you show me your `mapDispatchToProps`?